# Как очищать xhr.responseText при событии onprogress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть простейший код на ПХП, в цикле выводящий ответы:

```
ob_start();

$x = range(0, 20);

foreach ( $x as $value )
{
  usleep(250 * 1000);
  echo $value;
  flush();
  ob_flush();
}
```

Клиент запрашивает эту страницу черех аякс:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
  window.onload = function(  ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/parser/ajax.php',
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onprogress = function( event ) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        };
        return xhr;
      },
    });
  };
</script>
```

Задача выводит каждую итерацую в цикле в браузер.В примере: *console.log(xhr.responseText);*
Сейчас выводит

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
```

То есть конкатенирует вывод сервера ( **xhr.responseText** )
Нужно получить отдельную итерацию на каждом шаге:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас данные приходят по одной цифре, то почему бы просто не выводить последнюю цифру?

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
  window.onload = function(  ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/parser/ajax.php',
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onprogress = function( event ) {
          console.log( xhr.responseText.substr(-1) );
        };
        return xhr;
      },
    });
  };
</script>
```

**UPD**
Можно попробовать сохранять предыдущую длину сообщения, и потом просто читать все, что после этой длины

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
  window.onload = function(  ) {
    var loadedLen = 0; // без переменной доп не обойтись
    $.ajax({
      url: '/parser/ajax.php',
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onprogress = function( event ) {
          console.log( xhr.responseText.substr(loadedLen) );
          loadedLen = xhr.responseText.length;
        };
        return xhr;
      },
    });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: К сожалению это не так. Я просто упростил код, чтобы легче было понять.Приходит может как строка, так и обьект. Например, строка от исключения при ошибке и обьект при правильной работе.

Comment: @AlmaZ, ох, поздно увидел, что вы коммент обновили, написали про объект еще

Comment: @AlmaZ, responseText все равно имеет тип `String`, по идее, так что можете сначала доставать методом выше нужную часть, а потом уже пытаться парсить, как объект

Comment: Похоже, это пока единственный способ.